# Can I create an array in Ruby with default values?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Perl is pretty nice about default values:

```
: jmglov@laurana; perl -e '@foo; printf "%d\n", $foo[123]'
0
: jmglov@laurana; perl -e '%foo; printf "%d\n", $foo{bar}'
0
```

Ruby can do the same, at least for hashes:

```
>> foo = Hash.new(0)
=> {}
>> foo[:bar]
=> 0
```

But the same seemingly does not work for arrays:

```
>> foo = Array.new(0)
=> []
>> foo[123]
=> nil
>> foo[124] = 0
=> 0
>> foo[456] = 0
=> 0
>> foo[455,456]
=> [nil, 0]
```

Is it possible to supply a default value for arrays, so when they are auto-extended, they're filled with 0 instead of nil?

Of course I can work around this, but at a cost to expressiveness:

```
>> foo[457,458] = 890, 321
=> [890, 321]
>> foo[456] += 789
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+
>> foo.inject(0) {|sum, i| sum += (i || 0) }
=> 1211
>> foo.inject(:+)
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+
```

**Update 1:** One of my colleagues pointed out that I can use `#compact` to solve the `#inject` issue, and `#to_i` to solve the standard element-at-index issue:

```
>> foo.include? nil
=> true
>> foo.compact.inject(:+)
=> 1211
>> foo[456,457]
=> [0, 890, 321]
>> foo[455..457]
=> [nil, 0, 890]
>> foo[455..457].map(&:to_i)
=> [0, 0, 890]
```

**Update 2:** Thanks to [Andrew Grimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38765/andrew-grimm) for a solution to the `+=` issue:

```
>> foo = []
=> []
>> def foo.[](i)
>>   fetch(i) {0}
>> end
=> nil
>> foo[4]
=> 0
>> foo
=> []
>> foo[4] += 123
=> 123
>> foo
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, 123]
```

**Update 3:** this is starting to look like whack-a-mole!

```
>> foo
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, 123]
>> foo[-2..-1]
TypeError: can't convert Range into Integer
```

But we can deal with that:

```
>> def foo.[](index)
>>   if index.is_a? Range
>>     index.map {|i| self[i] }
>>   else
?>     fetch(index) { 0 }  # default to 0 if no element at index; will not cause auto-extension of array
>>   end
>> end
=> nil
>> foo
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, 123]
>> foo[-2..-1]
=> [nil, 123]
```

I now have to admit (sheepishly) that I'll subclass `Array` to avoid cluttering my code:

```
class MyClass
  class ArrayWithDefault < Array
    def [](index)
      if index.is_a? Range
        index.map {|i| self[i] }
      else
        fetch(index) { 0 }  # default to 0 if no element at index; will not cause auto-extension of array
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for all the creative solutions. TIMTOWTDI indeed!

Comment: If you need a sparse array, what's wrong with using a hash with integer keys?

Comment: I wonder if any PHP developers have complained that their array/hash data structure doesn't exist in Ruby.

Comment: Simon: I went with a hash in the first place, but there're a pain with some of the #maps and #injects I need to do.

Comment: Andrew: quick, is this a hash or an array? `foo[123] = 456` ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Given that Ruby returns `nil` for a non-existing element (as opposed to index-out-of-bounds type error), you could just use an "or":

```
a = [1,2,3]
puts a[5]  # => nil
puts a[5] || "a default"  # => a default
```

You could take the monkey patch approach, but you probably would not want to do this in anything larger than a 1-file script:

```
a = [1,2,3]
def a.[](index)
  self.at(index) || "a default"
end
puts a[5]   # => "a default"
```

Comment: Or you could do `a.fetch {"a default"}`.

Comment: Andrew: awesome! `def foo.[](i); fetch(i) {0} end`

Comment: Andrew: also, I didn't know about the `def obj.method` syntax. Much nicer than `obj.instance_eval { def method ... }`!

Comment: @Josh: That was by @Rob, not me. I just tidied up the indentation a little.

Comment: The `a[5] || "default"` and `a.fetch(5, "default")` techniques mean that your client code needs to say what the default should be. It would be nice if Array worked like Hash, which provides a default_proc and default_value for missing keys.

Comment: Also, `a = [nil, false]` has specified values. This is not the same as a "default": Maybe `a[0]` and `a[1]` should be nil and false, and only give a default value on actual missing keys. `fetch` does this, but it relies on the caller to set the default.

Answer (score 162):

Not auto extended, but initialized to the specified length with a default value:

```
>> Array.new(123, 0)  
=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Wouldn't that waste more memory?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way would be:

```
new_array = Array.new(size, default_value)
```

For example:

```
new_array = Array.new(5,"foo")
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would be overriding the `Array#[]` method and return the default value if there is no item

```
class Array         
  def [](index)
     self.at(index) ? self.at(index) : 0
  end
end
```

and

```
arr = [1,2,3]
puts arr[0]  # print 1
puts arr[5]  # print 0
```

Comment: I actually like this one, though rather than monkey-patching the Array class, I'll just instance_eval the override on the specific array I care about.

Comment: This actually raises an error: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Range into Integer`...

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with integers you can call `to_i`:

```
foo = []
foo[100]
#=> nil
foo[100].to_i
#=> 0
foo[100] = 3
foo[100]
#=> 3
```

**UPD**

Oh, I didn't read all topic :)

so you can use this:

```
foo.inject{|a,b| a.to_i + b.to_i }
```

which, actually, not the smartest one

Answer (score 3):

I'll put Johans elegant solution out there: `foo.compact.inject(:+)`

Answer (score 1):

I think an array is the wrong abstraction if you want to auto extend the array. Add another level of abstraction.

**Edit (from our discussion):** The important thing is that the code to achieve your goal is located in the right place (single responsibility principle), and that place is **not** your "client code", hence the need for a new class. Extending the existing Array class (through inheritance/mixin) is probably better than encapsulating the wanted behaviour in an entierly new class.

Comment: Without knowing what I am doing, judging whether the abstraction is correct seems fairly impossible. Array auto-extension is a Ruby feature, so why would I want to build another layer of abstraction to accomplish the same thing as the default Array behaviour gives me? Ruby is not Java. ;)

Comment: Agreed. What I am getting at is that you might want to encapsulate the extended behaviour in a class with a name that tells you what this class does rather than just monkey patch behaviour onto an existing class. This might be accomplished through inheritance/mixin or some other technique that ruby has.

Comment: You are right though that I am a C++ programmer learning some Ruby rather than a Ruby guru :)

Comment: Tobbe: hey, I've been there. My first Perl programs were basically C programs in Perl syntax, and my first Ruby ones were Perl in Ruby syntax. :)

Comment: Tobbe (re encapsulation): I see your point about subclassing / mixing in to get a good name, but what I really want to do is change the behaviour of a specific Array instance, but preserve its Array-ness--i.e. the name "Array" is still the best description of its behaviour. Why should I need to subclass Array to get a default value when I don't need to subclass Hash for the same?

Comment: Tobbe: you were right about the need for a subclass to avoid making a mess in the code after all. I'm just annoyed that Ruby's `Array` class doesn't support this by default--feels quite non-orthogonal to me.

Comment: An array is a data structure that is expected to have a certain behaviour no matter what language you use. And what you are asking for is not the expected behaviour of an array. So I must say that the Ruby API makes sense...