# Ruby: Create array items "on demand"

Tags: ruby, arrays

In Ruby with Hashes I can do this:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = "created #{k}" }
```

so that every time I try to access an item with a key that does not exists in the Hash it will call the block and create this new item and store with the key.

Is there a similar way to do this with Arrays?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I create an array in Ruby with default values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324654/can-i-create-an-array-in-ruby-with-default-values)

Comment: look [new(size) {|index| block }](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-new)

Comment: @Max, it's not the same problem, although it have a lot in common, the answers there do not provide a solution for my problem.

Comment: @ArupRakshit This is not what I'm looking for, was `new(size) {|index|block}` will create an Array of size `size`, it will not call the block again when I try to access a previously not existent key.

Answer (score 2):

The `Array.new` method can receive a block. It passes the index of the element and the result of the block is stored in the array.

```
Array.new(3) { |index| index ** 2 }
# => [0, 1, 4]
```

However, all the elements will be created the moment you call the method. They will also be stored in the block and there is no way to prevent that.

We can subclass `Array` and implement the desired `Hash`-like behavior.

```
class CustomArray < Array
  def [](index)
    if super.nil? then @default_proc.call self, index end
    super
  end
end

class << CustomArray
  def new(*arguments, **keyword_arguments, &block)
    if arguments.empty? and block
      super().tap do |array|
        array.instance_variable_set :@default_proc, block
      end
    else super end
  end
end
```

This way, the usual `Array` API is preserved. If a size parameter isn't passed with the block, it will be used as the default `Proc`.

```
array = CustomArray.new { |array, index| array[index] = index + 2 }

p array[10]
# => 12

p array
# => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 12]
```

See it run [here](http://ideone.com/fNmJ8p).

Note that this implementation is problematic due to the meaning of `nil`. In this case, it is defined to be the *empty* value due to how arrays work, which is reasonable in the context of contiguous memory. If you store an element at an index that is bigger than the size of the array, it will fill in the blanks with `nil` in order to indicate empty space between the last element and the element you just inserted.

If `nil` is a meaningful value, consider using a `Hash` with integer keys instead of an `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, no I do not think that is possible. If you are willing to do a little monkey-patching, you can add a similar method yourself. For example, by extending `Array` with a `get` method which accepts a Block, you can simulate what you want.

The `get` method will act like the regular `[]` when no Block is given. When you pass a Block and the value is `nil`, it will store whatever results from the Block at index `i`.

```
class Array
  def get(i, &block)
    return self[i] if !block || !self[i].nil?

    self[i] = block.call(i)
  end
end

array = [1, 2]
array.get(0) # => 1 

array.get(5) # => nil
array.get(5) { |i| "Created index #{i}" } # => "Created index 5"

p array # => [1, 2, nil, nil, nil, "Created index 5"]
```

Comment: I suggest that the method be named `fetch`. This would make it consistent with the `Hash` API. Also, I don't think a reader method should implicitly modify the array in place.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira `fetch` already exists for Array, it's similar to `[]` but throws an exception when the index is out of bounds. I did not want to change semantics of an existing method. I was just showing you could add an alternative method.