# Getting #with_index when inheriting from Array

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

I'd like my `SomeArray#map` to return an "array" of the `SomeArray` class.

```
class SomeArray < Array
  def map
    SomeArray.new(super)
  end
end

some_array = SomeArray.new(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
p some_array.class #=> SomeArray
p some_array.map { |e| e }.class #=> SomeArray
```

Except now I also want to be able to use the `Enumerator#with_index` instance method. So ideally something like this would work:

```
some_array.map.with_index { |e, i| e }.class #=> SomeArray
```

How would that work?

I've tried:

```
class SomeArray < Array
  def map
    SomeArray.new(super)
  end

  def with_index(offset = 0)
    super
  end
end

some_array = SomeArray.new(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
p some_array.class #=> SomeArray
p some_array.map.with_index { |e, i| e }.class #=> no implicit conversion of Enumerator into Integer (TypeError)
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're treating enumerable and array as if they're the same, which they're not.

Specifically, this in the map call: `SomeArray.new(super)`.

I can reproduce your error:

```
[6] pry(main)> Array.new [1].map
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Enumerator into Integer
```

Now, when you pass a block to `map`, it works:

```
Array.new([1].map { |x| x })  
=> [1]
```

But in your `map.with_index` you're not doing this.

You can do something like this:

```
module Foo
  include Enumerable
  def map
    puts "calling my map"
    super
  end
  def with_index
    puts "calling my with_index"
    super
  end
end

class MyArr < Array
  include Foo
end

puts MyArr.new([1]).map.with_index { |x, y| [x,y] }
# calling my map
# calling my with_index
# 1
# 0
```

Which kind of begs the question of why you're writing this class that just calls `super`. But in the case that you want to modify the default functionality of enumerable, this is one way.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference between `Array.new [1].map` and `Array.new([1].map { |x| x }) `? Does it have something to do with one instantiation of an array includes the `Enumerable` module and one doesn't? Because they are both arrays `[1].class #=> Array` and `Array.new.class #=> Array` So I'm confused about what the difference is.

Comment: Generally you should use `[ ]` brackets, but Array.new has some additional capabiliies (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324654/can-i-create-an-array-in-ruby-with-default-values). In the case that you create a MyArray class which inherits from Array, you'd need to use `MyArray.new` because `[ ]` would use the standard Array class. Because of right associativity (the rule that often makes parenthesis unnecessary), `Array.new 1.map(&:class)` is the same as `Array.new(1.map(&:class))` but in either case the `Array.new` is redundant. You can remove it and the effect will be the same.

Comment: The difference between  `Array.new [1].map` and `Array.new([1].map { |x| x})` is not the parenthesis (which can be removed with no effect). It's the fact t hat `[1].map` (map with no block) returns an Enumerable while `[1].map { |x| x }` returns an Array.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that `map` is an Array method while `with_index` is an `Enumerator` method.

- Array methods are defined to just call `super`, and convert the output array to `SomeArray`.
- Enumerator methods are defined with a `to_enum` first, convert the output to an Array and then to `SomeArray`.

It probably isn't the best structure for what you want to do, and isn't very efficient either. It's just a proof a concept!

```
class SomeArray < Array
  # Array methods are overwritten here :
  [:map, :select, :reject].each do |array_method_name|
    define_method array_method_name do |*p, &block|
      SomeArray.new(super(*p, &block).to_a)
    end
  end

  # Enumerator methods are defined for SomeArray here :
  [:with_index, :with_object].each do |enum_method_name|
    define_method enum_method_name do |*p, &block|
      SomeArray.new(to_enum.public_send(enum_method_name, *p, &block).to_a)
    end
  end
end

some_array = SomeArray.new(%w(foo bar baz biz))

p some_array.map { |s| s * 2 }.with_index.select { |_, i| i.even? }
#=> [["foofoo", 0], ["bazbaz", 2]]
p some_array.map { |s| s * 2 }.with_index.select { |_, i| i.even? }.class
#=> SomeArray
```