# Ruby Array default value?

Tags: ruby

I have hundreds of arrays that am normalizing for a CSV.

```
[
  ["foo", "tom", nil,     1,   4, "cheese"],
  ["foo", "tom", "fluffy",nil, 4],
  ["foo", "tom", "fluffy",1, nil],
  ...
]
```

Currently to make them all equal length i am finding the max length and setting to a value.

`rows.each { |row| row[max_index] ||= nil }`

this is cool because it makes the array length equal to the new length.

Instead of appending a bunch of `nil`s at the end I needed to append `COLUMN_N` where N is the index (1-based).

```
table_rows.each do |row|
  last_index = row.length - 1
  (last_index..max_index).to_a.each { |index| row[index] ||= "COLUMN_#{index+1}" }
end
```

Which seemed like an awkward way to have a default value that is a function of the index.

Comment: We'd like to see your attempt at solving this. Without that it looks like you want us to write code for you, which isn't what SO is for. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421, which will help explain what are expected.

Comment: @theTinMan respect. i'll update my question

Comment: @theTinMan updated.

Answer (score 2):

To get a default value instead of `nil` you can use [`fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-fetch):

```
row = ["foo", "tom", "fluffy", 1, 4]
row.fetch(7) { |i| "COLUMN_#{i + 1}" }
=> "COLUMN_8"
```

But it won't fill the array for you.

Also see: [Can I create an array in Ruby with default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324654/can-i-create-an-array-in-ruby-with-default-values)

Answer (score 2):

You can't choose a default value for filling elements with `[]=` method. But you can easily do something like this if there aren't other `nil`s that you don't want to replace.

```
row.each_with_index.map { |item, index| item.nil? ? "column_#{index}": item }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it could work for you.

```
class Array
  def push_with_default(item, index, &block)
    new_arr = Array.new([self.size + 1, index].max, &block)
    self[index] = item
    self.map!.with_index { |n, i| n.nil? ? new_arr[i] : n }
  end
end

>> array = [1,2,5,9]
[
    [0] 1,
    [1] 2,
    [2] 5,
    [3] 9
]
>> array.push_with_default(2, 10) { |i| "column_#{i}" }
[
    [ 0] 1,
    [ 1] 2,
    [ 2] 5,
    [ 3] 9,
    [ 4] "column_4",
    [ 5] "column_5",
    [ 6] "column_6",
    [ 7] "column_7",
    [ 8] "column_8",
    [ 9] "column_9",
    [10] 2
]
```

I don't believe a method like this exists on Array already though.