# how to work with Array without changing its initial values?

Tags: ruby, dictionary

I am a newbie. so far I have been in touch with two languages, ruby and python. I also read a couple of essays about C++ pointers, I had a bit of confusion with Array Objects and how to manipulate the value inside. I found that including an exclamation mark in the method, can change the array without assignment. however sometimes it doesn't; I appreciate it if someone can explain the nature of array, what are they, are they a location to store values, or are they the collection of values? more specifically, if I divide ruby array functions into two groups: the one that can change the values of array without assignment directly, and the ones who need assignment, could you please give me a couple of examples
In the following example, I don't understand why the values of my initial array is changed. 
here is my code example:

```
edges = [[[1, 2], [100, 200]], [[700, 400], [1000, 2000]]]

new_edges = Array.new(edges)
new_edges.map{|edge| edge.map{|point| point.insert(0, 808912)}}

edges
#=> [[[808912, 1, 2], [808912, 100, 200]], [[808912, 700, 400], [808912, 1000, 2000]]]

new_edges
#=> [[[808912, 1, 2], [808912, 100, 200]], [[808912, 700, 400], [808912, 1000, 2000]]]
```

what I believe will happen, is that values in `edges` won't be changed, and the `new_edges` will be changed. I do appreciate for your help.

Comment: It looks like you are creating `new_edges` array twice. Once with Array.new, and Twice with new_edges.map. Why are you doing it this way? What happened when you rant this code in terminal?

Comment: is there a better way of doing this? Could you please give me some suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Well Array.new(edges) seems okay... but what's the problem? You need to include the results when you run this code, ie. error message, or the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array in one step using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908413/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-one-step-using-ruby)

Comment: what it is initially: [[[1, 2], [100, 200]], [[700, 400], [1000, 2000]]], what I want: [[[808912, 1, 2], [808912, 100, 200]], [[808912, 700, 400], [808912, 1000, 2000]]], and I need to use the initial value later

Comment: the first puts result from terminal is: [[[808912, 1, 2], [808912, 100, 200]], [[808912, 700, 400], [808912, 1000, 2000]]]. the second puts result is: 
[[[808912, 1, 2], [808912, 100, 200]], [[808912, 700, 400], [808912, 1000, 2000]]]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202034/discussion-between-messiz-qin-and-james-h).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has the same problems as this would in Python:

```
edges = [[[1, 2], [100, 200]], [[700, 400], [1000, 2000]]]
new_edges = list(edges)
for edge in edges:
    for point in edge:
        point.insert(0, 808912)
print(edges)
```

I.e. you transform the outer array, but the inner arrays are only held by reference, and thus changing one (by `insert`) is changing the deep content of both `edges` and `new_edges`. These kinds of problems are very easily understood by stepping through your code with [this tool](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html) (despite the name, it works for both Python and Ruby).

In Ruby, instead of using `insert`, which modifies an array, you can use `+`, which does not:

```
edges = [[[1, 2], [100, 200]], [[700, 400], [1000, 2000]]]
new_edges = edges.map { |edge| edge.map { |point| [808912] + point } }
# => [[[808912, 1, 2], [808912, 100, 200]], [[808912, 700, 400], [808912, 1000, 2000]]]
edges
# => [[[1, 2], [100, 200]], [[700, 400], [1000, 2000]]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I also find another way: 'new_edges = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(edges))' 'new_edges.map{|point| point.insert(0, 808912)}'

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more general situation that illustrates the problem you are having and ways of correcting it. Suppose we had the following nested arrays:

```
a0 = [1, 2]
a1 = [3, 4]
a = [a0, a1]
  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]] 
edges = [a]
  #=> [[[1, 2], [3, 4]]]
```

`a0`, `a1`, `a` and `edges` have unique object ids:

```
edges.object_id           #=> 1208140 

a.object_id               #=> 1085620  
edges[0].object_id        #=> 1085620 

a0.object_id              #=> 0977080 
a[0].object_id            #=> 0977080
edges[0][0].object_id     #=> 0977080

a1.object_id              #=> 0995980 
a[1].object_id            #=> 0995980
edges[0][1].object_id     #=> 0995980
edges[0][1][0].object_id  #=> 7
```

For readability I have removed the first seven digits of each of the object ids, which in all cases is `4833847`. Note `edges[0][1][0] #=> 3` and `3.object_id #=> 7`. For reasons of efficiency, integers (and certain other Ruby objects have fixed, smallish, object ids.

Now create a new array from `edges` using the method [Array::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-c-new):

```
new_edges = Array.new(edges)
  #=> [[[1, 2], [3, 4]]]
```

Examine the (last six digits of the) object ids:

```
new_edges.object_id          #=> 2400460 (different than edges.object_id)
new_edges[0].object_id       #=> 1085620 (same as edges[0].object_id)
new_edges[0][0].object_id    #=> 0977080 (same as edges[0][0].object_id)
new_edges[0][1].object_id    #=> 0995980 (same as edges[0][1].object_id)
new_edges[0][1][0].object_id #=> 7       (same as edges[0][1][0].object_id)
```

It is seen that `new_edges` is a new object, but all of its nested arrays and elements are the same objects as the corresponding nested arrays and elements in `edges`.

Now let's do the following:

```
edges[0][1][0] = 5
edges[0][1][0].object_id #=> 11
```

Then

```
edges
  #=> [[[1, 2], [5, 4]]] 
new_edges 
  #=> [[[1, 2], [5, 4]]]
```

`new_edges` was changed as well as `edges` because `edges[0][1]` and `new_edges[0][1]` are the same object (array) and we just changed the first element of that object.

How do we avoid changing `new_edges` when `edges` is changed?

Firstly, note that `new_edges = Array.new(edges)` can be replaced with `new_edges = edges.dup`. As before, `edges` and `new_edges` will be different objects but all of their corresponding nested arrays will the same objects.

We wish to define `new_edges` by making a *deep copy* of `edges`, so that changes to the latter will not affect the former, and vice-versa:

```
new_edges = edges.map { |a| a.map { |aa| aa.dup } }  
  #=> [[[1, 2], [3, 4]]]
new_edges.object_id       #=> 2134620 (different than edges.object_id) 
new_edges[0].object_id    #=> 2134600 (different than edges[0].object_id)
new_edges[0][0].object_id #=> 2134580 (different than edges[0][0].object_id)
new_edges[0][1].object_id #=> 2134560 (different than edges[0][1].object_id)
```

Now change a nested element in `edges` and observe the values of `edges` and `new_edges`:

```
edges[0][1][0] = 5

edges
  #=> [[[1, 2], [5, 4]]] 
new_edges
  #=> [[[1, 2], [3, 4]]]
```

It is seen that `new_edges` is not modified.

If there are greater levels of nesting it can become tedious and error-prone to make a deep copy using `map` and `dup`. An easier way is to use [Marshal#dump](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) and [Marshal#load](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Marshal.html#method-c-load), which create deep copies of a wide range of Ruby objects that may contain multiple levels of nested objects:

```
edges
  #=> [[[1, 2], [5, 4]]] 
new_edges = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(edges))
  #=> [[[1, 2], [5, 4]]]
```

Changes to `edges` will now leave `new_edges` unaffected.

```
edges[0][1][0] = 3

edges
  #=> [[[1, 2], [3, 4]]] 
new_edges
  #=> [[[1, 2], [5, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You start out with

```
edges = [[[1, 2], [100, 200]], [[700, 400], [1000, 2000]]]
```

Dup won't work here since it's a nested array, so you need to deep_dup it before doing what you wanna do. (If you don't want to mutate the original array)

Here's an example of a monkeypatched deep_dup (Array)

```
  def deep_dup
    new_arr = []
    self.each do |ele|
      if ele.is_a? Array
        new_arr << ele.deep_dup
      else
        new_arr << ele
      end
    end
   new_arr
  end
```

You can obv. do this a lot cleaner but whatever

EDIT: Array has a built-in deep_dup method, use that. I always thought Ruby left deep_dup up to implementation, but I was wrong.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have `deep_dup`. ActiveSupport does (and thus Rails does as well).

Comment: Oh, I just googled it and must have misread the documentation. My bad, I just saw #deep_dup, but it must have been ActiveSupport and not Ruby. Also, your solution is way more space and time effective, haha. Just using a method that doesn't mutate the original array is a lot better than deep_dupping the original then using methods that do mutate.

Comment: A somewhat hackish way to deep clone an array without using Rails is `Marshal.load Marshal.dump(my_array)`. `Marshal.dump` packs the array into a string format, which `Marshal.load` unpacks into an array.